# How to identify different platforms in API of expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building expressjs/nodejs application. Now I want to identify whether the request came from web/android/ios? What should be the ideal and most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: platform information can be collected on client side and sent to express server using headers

Comment: Ok, so how can I separate android/web/ios using `user-agent` on server side?

Comment: What do you want to use this information for?  Just for logging and statistics?  Or are you trying to make decisions on how the site should behave?

Comment: @jfriend00 when user access login API , at that time I want to get this flag and when I am sending push notification, at that time I will use this flag whether send it to APN or FCM?

Comment: Well, if the request is coming from your own android or iOS app, you can just have them tell you how they'd like to receive push since the client knows what platform its on.

Comment: Ok, so isn't it possible with `user-agent` header?

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to identify whether the request came from web/android/ios?
>   What should be the ideal and most efficient way of doing that?

You could use this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-useragent

to expose the information you want for your REST endpoint. Not sure if it is THE BEST way or if there IS a best way, but I have made good experiences with it.

You could ask for the information like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var useragent = require('express-useragent');

app.use(useragent.express());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.useragent);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

The info you might receive could look like this:

```
{
  "isMobile":false,
  "isDesktop":true,
  "isBot":false,
  .....
  "browser":"Chrome",
  "version":"17.0.963.79",
  "os":"Windows 7",
  "platform":"Microsoft Windows",
  "source":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79..."
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. My doubt is when the request is from iOS device , then how would I know from `isMobile` flag ?

Comment: If it is an iOS handheld device, "isMobile" should evaluate to `true` and "os" to `iOS` or something like this. Do you have testing devices? You can try this out.